# Firebase Authentication limit

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm developing an Android application and I'm using Firebase Authentication to let the user sign in using Google account in my Android application. Does the Firebase Authentication get limit of how many users can log in? Are there any restrictions on how many users can log in at one time? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The selected answer is wrong. Jo E. has provided the correct answer.

Answer (score -10, accepted):

This depends on what version you paying for. The free edition has a limit of 100 connection at any time. The paid version have a limit of 100,000 connections. Check on their [pricing site](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) for more info. It has more information on the other limitations.

Comment: The 100 connections refers to the number of Realtime Database connections not the number of devices that can use Google/Facebook authentication. Auth is free.

Comment: Firebase Authentication service is free in all plans. I just now found out.

Answer (score 22):

If you are just concerned about the authentication, excluding phone authentication. Then here is the answer from the [Firebase Pricing FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#pricing)

> all Authentication features beyond phone authentication are free.

Here is the full statement:

> Which products are paid? Which are free?
>
> Firebase's paid infrastructure products are the Realtime Database,
>   Storage, functions, Hosting, Test Lab, and phone authentication. We
>   offer a free tier for all of these features.
>
> Firebase also has many free products: Analytics, Cloud Messaging, the
>   Notifications composer, Remote Config, App Indexing, Dynamic Links,
>   Invites, and Crash Reporting. You can use an unlimited amount of any
>   of these products in all plans, including our free Spark plan. In
>   addition, **all Authentication features beyond phone authentication are
>   free.**

Answer (score 0):

These changes can be updating anytime.
refer to this link for updated details - https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits